# Дирректория для php extensions

Tags: php, pecl

У меня установлен php, хочу поставить расширение redis. В какую папку нужно его устанавливать?

Comment: Мдааа.... У вас OS какая? Речь идёт о [php/pecl-расширении](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis) или о библиотеке-обёртке, к примеру, [predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis)?

Comment: windows у меня, поставить нужно расширение https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases

Comment: Это не расширение, это реализация Redis Server для винды, причём только 2.8 версия, т.е. без [Redis Cluster](http://goo.gl/TPOvcU). Кроме того, для php необходимо установать специальное расширение о котором я писал выше. С виндой помочь не могу и даже пытаться не буду. Дело в том, что сегодня вам понабился redis, завтра memcached, а послезавтра Sphinx Search или иной сервис/расширение у котрого поддержка win может быть слабая или вообще её не быть. Коль вы уже задумались использовать redis + php, то странно, что ещё не на Linux. Наверно, используете какой-нгибудь OpenServer или Denwer.

Comment: Вы конечно подождите, может быть кто-нибудь ответит, но я сомневаюсь. Рекомендую использовать виртуализацию, к примеру, бесплатный [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), либо для ubuntu существует [WUBI](http://goo.gl/vYCwWu). А уже там "трава не расти": `apt-get install -y redis-server php5-redis`, либо если нет желание засерать свою хост машину, вы можете воспользоваться моим [docker-контейнером](https://github.com/romeOz/docker-redis) для Redis: `docker run --name redis -d -p 6379:6379 romeoz/docker-redis:2.8`

Comment: Vagrant для разработчика самая нужная вещь